# Understanding the guard function and list comprehension

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension, monads, guard-statement

I am learning about the `guard` function from the book 'Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!' by Miran Lipovaca.

For the following example:

```
ghci> [1..50] >>= (\x -> guard('7' `elem` show x) >> return x)
[7, 17, 27, 37, 47]
```

I know that `guard` takes a Boolean value, and if the value is `True`, guard takes `()` and puts it in a minimal default context and succeeds.
If the value is `False`, then `guard` makes a failed monadic value.

However, I don't understand how guard works in the above example to create the resulting list `[7, 17, 27, 37, 47]`. What is passed as `x` in the lambda function, is it 1? Further, if `` ('7' `elem` show x) `` evaluates to `False`, then wouldn't the empty list be returned? How exactly does the final result list come to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the list `Monad` instance:

- `>>=` is `concatMap` with the arguments flipped
- `guard condition` is equivalent to `if condition then [()] else []`

And in any `Monad` instance, `a >> b` = `a >>= \_ -> b`, so in the list instance this is equivalent to `concatMap (\_ -> b) a`.

Therefore your code desugars to this:

```
concatMap
  (\x -> concatMap
    (\_ -> [x])
    (if '7' `elem` show x then [()] else []))
  [1..50]
```

So the outer `concatMap` produces as an intermediate value a list of 50 elements, each being a list, which is a singleton list of the input value if its string representation contains a digit `7`, or else the empty list:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [7], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [17], …]
```

Which is then concatenated to produce the final result `[7, 17, 27, 37, 47]`.

> What is passed as x in the lambda function, is it 1?

It’s *each* element of the input list, `1` through `50`.

The inner `concatMap` produces `[x]` if the condition is true and `[]` if the condition is false, because `guard` produces a list of one element (the dummy `()`) if the condition is true and an empty list if it’s false—this may be easier to see if you rephrase it as an equivalent:

```
map (\_ -> x) (if '7' `elem` show x then [()] else [])
-- or
if '7' `elem` show x then [x] else []
```